Persisting of entities with no id, custom generation strategy
Here's the goal: I need keys to be automatically incremented in the following fashion: "p1", "p2", etc. Postgres can't have sequences like that, so I set a default value like this (I omit irrelevant columns):
-- schema.sql

CREATE SEQUENCE p_sequence;

CREATE TABLE product
(
    id                      VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'p' || nextval('p_sequence'),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


package com.example.productapi.data.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String productId;
}

Here comes the problem: when the user hits the POST endpoint and tries to persist an entity with no id, Hibernate throws IdentifierGenerationException (which is then translated by Spring). It's because it does't allow persisting of entities with no ids unless there's some @GeneratedValue strategy. Which is not SEQUENCE since I don't relly on a sequence completely. It would be nice if Hibernate relaxed and just trusted in the DB (which would provide a default value). However, it's not going to happen.
What are the workarounds for this?

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

You are using sequence. So better annotate with GenerationType.SEQUENCE
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

Just make sure your ddl-auto is not set to create table everytime. Else the sequence will not work as expected.
Product class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Id
    private String id;
}


I executed save 3 times, below is the result.
https://snipboard.io/ljnsbc.jpg
Infact both identity and sequence works if you don't do any auto ddl change. Database will take care of this.

The sequence won't generate values like "p1". Postgres sequences may only generate integers, afaik

It will generate.
"id"
"p1"
"p2"
"p3"
I will update some more info in my answer
